# Generating subsets using length/2 and ord_subset/2

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am a beginner in prolog. I tried this in swipl interpreter:

```
?- length(Lists, 3), ord_subset(Lists, [1, 2, 3, 4]).
false.
```

expecting to get all length-3 lists that are subsets of [1, 2, 3, 4] like [1, 2, 3] or [1, 2, 4]. Why do i get false?

Notice: both length and ord_subset are builtin functions (or whatever they are called) in SWI-Prolog.

Comment: You could do this if [ord_subset/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ord_subset/2) was declared as `ord_subset(?Sub, ?Super)`. At the moment, it is `ord_subset(+Sub, +Super)`, meaning both have to be proper lists.

Comment: The introductory material for the Prolog manual describes the [notational conventions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc) used to describe predicates. That includes the indications of whether an argument must be instantiated on the call or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get a solution because the `ord_subset/2` predicate only *checks* if a list is a subset of another list; it does not generate subsets.

Here is one simplistic way to define a predicate that does what you seem to be after:

```
subset_set([], _).
subset_set([X|Xs], S) :-
    append(_, [X|S1], S),
    subset_set(Xs, S1).
```

This assumes that these are "ordsets", that is, sorted lists without duplicates.

You will notice that the subset happens to be also a subsequence. We could have written instead:

```
subset_set(Sub, Set) :-
    % precondition( ground(Set) ),
    % precondition( is_list(Set) ),
    % precondition( sort(Set, Set) ),
    subseq_list(Sub, Set).

subseq_list([], []).
subseq_list([H|T], L) :-
    append(_, [H|L1], L),
    subseq_list(T, L1).
```

With either definition, you get:

```
?- length(Sub, 3), subset_set(Sub, [1,2,3,4]).
Sub = [1, 2, 3] ;
Sub = [1, 2, 4] ;
Sub = [1, 3, 4] ;
Sub = [2, 3, 4] ;
false.
```

You can even switch the order of the two subgoals in the example query, but this is probably the better way to write it.

However, the second argument **must be** ground; if it is not:

```
?- subset_set([A,B], [a,B]), B = a.
A = B, B = a ; Not a real set, is it?
false.
```

Comment: `[A,A]` is not a set - it contains a duplicate. Otherwise `[A,B]` would be a "set", provided it always holds that `A @< B` (which cannot be guaranteed, but many assume it). So `library(ordsets)` is inherently broken.

Comment: @false Yes, I have to agree that `library(ordsets)` has to be used with so much care that it becomes almost useless.